# Matplotlib: How to draw y = -x in a log-log plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm drawing with Matplotlib a log-log plot to exploit the correlation 
between some nodes using their assortativity.

I successfully drawn the y = x line but now I'm struggling with the y = -x.

Here is the code I'm using:

```py
plt.xscale("log")
plt.yscale("log")
plt.grid()
x = np.arange(0, 1500)
plt.plot(x, 0.35*x, ":", color="r")
plt.title("Assortativity")
plt.show()
```

- This is the final plot I want to show:

  - red line is what I get from code I pasted
  - blue line is what I need

[image]

Comment: The red line has a positive gradient. So has your linear expression. 

You could probably fix this by adding a minus infront of 0.35*x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not plot y = -x (for positive x values) in a log-log plot, because you cannot plot negative values in it. The blue line you are showing does not represent a negative linear relationship either (like y = -mx + n), because that would not look straight in a log-log plot. You can get that "straight" line downwards like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.xscale("log")
plt.yscale("log")
plt.grid()
x = np.arange(0, 1500)
k = 0.35
plt.plot(x, k * x, ":", color="r")
plt.plot(x, np.exp(-np.log(x) + np.log(x[-1] * k)), color="b")
plt.title("Assortativity")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
plt.plot(x, .35*1500/x, ":", color="b")
```